# Polynomial irreducible over an extension with coprime degree.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $a$ be a square free integer and $P(X)=X^n-a$.
>
> By Einstein's criterion P is irreducible. Now let $k$ be an extension pf $\Bbb{Q}$ of degree $d$, and $\beta$ the positive root of $P.$

I would like to prove that if $[k(\beta):\Bbb{Q}(\beta)]=[k:\Bbb{Q}]$ then $X^n-a$ is irreducible over $k[X]$. Already, I first proved the converse, but I am stuck visualizing how the fact that $[k(\beta):\Bbb{Q}(\beta)]=d$ implies the result.

$P$ is a degree $n$ so if we have $P=QR$ the degree of $Q,R$ is less than $n\le 2.$

I have another question (it's a exercise). I proved that if $(n,d)=1$ then $X^n-a$ is irreducible, now I would *to prove that* $P$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)[X].$ So I need to prove that $(n,2)$ are coprime but I don't see why is true.

Edit: Perhaps I misunderstand the definition of square-free, I would translate it literally: $a$ is not divisible by a square. So it implies that for $a=p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ that $\alpha_j=1$ for at least one $j.$

Comment: Squarefree means $a_j=1$ for *all* $j$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $[k(\beta):{\mathbb Q}]$ is equal to both $[k(\beta):k][k:{\mathbb Q}]$ and $[k(\beta):{\mathbb Q}(\beta)][{\mathbb Q}(\beta):{\mathbb Q}]$.

Comment: ah, so we have:  what I want*d=d*n so what I want is $n$, and therefore $X^n-a$ is irreducible, right?

Comment: Yes. If $X^n-a=QR$ over $k[X]$, then $Q(\beta)=0$ (say) and hence $[k(\beta):k] \leq {\sf deg}(Q) <n$.

Comment: Thanks +1, does I have to use that to prove that $X^n -a$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)[X]$? Then I must prove that $[\Bbb{Q}(i)(\beta):\Bbb{Q}(\beta)]=[\Bbb{Q}(i):\Bbb{Q}]$ which is equivalent to prove that $[\Bbb{Q}(i)(\beta):\Bbb{Q}(\beta)]=2$ which is correct because $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ because it contains only reals numbers. Right ?

Comment: Absolutely. By the way, you can accept this answer when you have no more questions.

Comment: I should have seen your hint alone... Thanks for your answer and your time.